# How to make custom button in android

Tags: android

I Want to make custom Buttons That look some thing like these

[image]

I Searched a Lot but could not make it.What am i supposed to do! i want to make then in xml not in photoshop.

Comment: You need to create a drawable xml resource and use it as background of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learn to make custom drawable xml resource.
The following is to set up button to look nicely in a minute
Probably you can get some ideas from their codes !

http://www.mindfreakerstuff.com/2012/09/50-useful-android-custom-button-style-set-1/

Answer (score 0):

A way to reach what you want to do is to create two image for buttons, one for button not-pressed and one for pressed button called "buttonup" and "buttondown" relatively, and put them in res/drawable folder. Together these you need the following xml file named "selector.xml":

```
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/buttondown" /> <!-- pressed -->

<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/buttonup" /> <!-- focused -->

<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/buttonup" /> <!-- default -->
```

Now you may implement all adding this code in your layout xml file within button tag:

android:background="@drawable/selector"

Comment: i know that much! look at the snap shot in my question. i want buttons like those. look at the edges

Comment: yes...and what would be the problem? open your image editor and create them like you want...use my explanation in such a way to implent as shown in the snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

On android 4.3 you can use **ImageButton**

on xml

```
    <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/android_button"
    android:onClick="doSomthing" />
```

on code

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity 
{

 ImageButton imageButton;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
 }

 public void doSomthing(View v)
 {
     //what happan when button pressed
 }
}
```

The
 android:src="@drawable/android_button"

"android_button" is the image name in res/drawable

Comment: what will be that "android_button"? i want buttons exactly look like in the snap shot